# Range based loops with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I want to iterate an array inside a function. the following code won't compile.

```
void printArr(int arr[])
{
    for (auto x : arr)
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}
```

I know arr is actually a pointer to the first element. 
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the range based loop needs an array type, a standard library container, or something with suitable `begin` and `end` iterators. In your function, `arr` is just a pointer (a function parameter such as `int arr[]` is adjusted to `int* arr`).

From a practical perspective, the range based loop could not know how many elements to print, so it would make no sense for it to deal with a pointer.

You could try passing the array by reference instead.

```
template <size_t N>
void printArr(const int (&arr)[N])
{
    for (auto x : arr)
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}
```

Where a template function has been used to allow for arrays of different lengths. You could also make the element type a template parameter:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void printArr(const T (&arr)[N])
{
  ....
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because array arguments are depleted to pointers and range based loops require an array or a container type. You can instead try the following code:

```
template <typename T, size_t sz>
void printArr(const T (&arr)[sz])
{
    for (auto x : arr)
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}
```

[Live demo here](http://ideone.com/1EhsBa)

This code passes the reference of array instead of address.